# Why are contravariant type parameters in function parameters considered in "out" position?

Tags: generics, kotlin, contravariance

Hard for me to describe in english, but here's the issue:

```
class Consumer<in T> {
    fun consume(t: T) {}
}

class Accepter<in T>() {
    // ERROR: Type parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'out' position in type Consumer<T>
    fun acceptWith(value: T, consumer: Consumer<T>) {}
}
```

It can be fixed like this:

```
fun <U : T> acceptWith(value: T, consumer: Consumer<U>) {}
```

But I don't understand the issue. It doesn't seem unsafe to allow `Consumer<T>`. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters which themselves allow input are logically equivalent to return values for a function, which are obviously in "out" position.

Consider this simple example:

```
interface Worker<in T> {
    fun work(output: Consumer<T>)
}
```

This is logically equivalent to

```
interface Worker<in T> {
    fun work(): T
}
```

`work()` can *output* a value in either case.

An example of this failing:

```
fun bad(anyWorker: Worker<Any>) {
    val stringWorker: Worker<String> = anyWorker
    stringWorker.work(Consumer { value: String -> /* value could be Any since it came from anyWorker! */ })
}
```

However, we can solve this by introducing a new type parameter for the function:

```
interface Worker<in T> {
    fun <U : T> work(output: Consumer<U>)
}
```

Now, `work()` will only be allowed to call the `Consumer` with some specific subtype of `T` that the consumer must be able to consume. For example, lets imagine that work takes another argument, as in the original question, and actually does something:

```
class Worker<in T> {
    private val inputs = mutableListOf<T>()

    fun <U : T> work(input: U, output: Consumer<U>) {
        inputs += input
        output.accept(input)
    }
}
```

By introducing the type parameter `U`, we can ensure that `input` and `output` are consistent with respect to each other, but still allow `Worker<Any>` to extend `Worker<String>`.

Answer (score 5):

The argument position is called contravariant because its variance goes in contrary direction w.r.t. the class variance. It means that the supertypes of a class can take the subtypes of an argument type as a parameter and vice versa.

Let's consider some actual parameter type `S`. In this example a type `Accepter<S>`, which is a supertype of `Accepter<Any>`, must take a *subtype* of `Consumer<Any>` as a parameter, but with the given signature it takes `Consumer<S>`, that isn't a subtype of `Consumer<Any>`, but rather a supertype of it.

Another example why this argument type would be unsafe if allowed. Let's consider the following implementations of `Accepter` and `Consumer`:

```
class AnyAccepter : Accepter<Any>() {
    override fun acceptWith(value: Any, consumer: Consumer<Any>) {
        consumer.consume(Any())
    }
}

class StringConsumer : Consumer<String>() {
    override fun consume(t: String) {
        println(t.length)
    }
}
fun main() {
    val anyAccepter = AnyAccepter()
    val stringAccepter: Accepter<String> = anyAccepter

    // here we're passing a StringConsumer, but the implementation expects Consumer<Any>
    stringAccepter.acceptWith("x", StringConsumer())
}
```

With these implementations you'll get an unsound program, which will result in ClassCastException at run time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.String 
    at contravariance.StringConsumer.consume(consumers.kt:27)
    at contravariance.AnyAccepter.acceptWith(consumers.kt:23)
    at contravariance.ConsumersKt.main(consumers.kt:36)
```

Comment: Thanks for the full example, it led me to the summary I was looking for: "Contravariant and invariant arguments are outputs of the function, much like a return type would be, since they can be passed value. It's equivalent to `acceptWith(): T` which is also disallowed"

Comment: I wrote a new answer based on what I learned from your examples that I think better answers my specific question, which is why a parameter can be considered in "out" position. You illustrate the issue and give a good example of it failing, which I was struggling to do. However, your answer seems to respond to a question I didn't actually have: "What is contravariance?" Thanks!

Comment: Please do read over my answer and let me know if I made any mistakes. I still find variance to be a little confusing, and the language around it is tricky to get right. I don't want to mislead anyone.

Comment: @YonaAppletree yes, that's another valid perspective on the same thing.

Comment: @Ilya Thank you for explanation. Can we assume that if the class class Accepter<in T> would never be 'open' then this declaration would be safe?