# Kotlin generics fail when deduced from lambda argument

Tags: generics, kotlin, lambda

Today I encountered strange behavior while creating some Kotlin generics. Code below illustrates the problem.

**MCVE**

```
class Generic<T>(private val initial: T? = null, private val source: (T)->Unit) {
    fun test(value: T) = source(value)
}

fun <T> createGeneric(initial: T? = null, source: (T)->Unit) = Generic(initial, source)

fun test() {
    val generic = createGeneric(null) { arg: Int -> println(arg) }
    generic.test(42) 
}
```

The line `generic.test(42)` produces error:

> The integral literal does not conform to the expected type Nothing

Question: How can `T` be deduced as `Nothing`, since I pass `{ arg: Int -> println(arg) }` lambda, which is `(Int)->Unit`?. I double-checked type of variable `generic`, and it's deduced as `Generic<Nothing>`.

Also, if the type is deduced as `Nothing`, why it allows to pass lambda of type `(Int)->Unit` as second argument?

[Kotlin Playground Example](https://pl.kotl.in/WZ0-ig-Nf)

Comment: I was able to get this to work by explicitly declaring that `createGeneric` returns a `Generic<T>`

Answer (score 2):

Because functions are [contravariant in their argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961416/why-are-contravariant-type-parameters-in-function-parameters-considered-in-out), `(Int) -> Unit` is a subtype of `(Nothing) -> Unit`. So both arguments are acceptable for `T=Nothing` and that's what gets inferred.

Yes, they are also both acceptable for `T=Int`, but Kotlin chooses the more specific type.

Comment: That's pretty nasty in my opinion. Shouldn't Nothing be handled differently in this situation by compiler? Sounds like language pitfall to be honest.

Comment: I agree it looks reasonable. I suggest raising this on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your lambda can never execute, because the function invocation `source(value)` can never happen.

In Kotlin, whenever you have a function that doesn't finish, the function returns a type `Nothing`.

If you were to define the type that your Generic takes in `Generic<Int>` then you would get rid of that error. But because you don't, the compiler tries to infer it based on the value that you're passing in `createGeneric(null)`. Because you're passing in `null`.

When you pass in null on a parameter type, it resolves to `Nothing?` and when you pass it into a nullable parameter type it resolves to `Nothing`. 
`Nothing` in Kotlin, is the *absence* of type. Because `null` itself doesn't have a type, you get `Nothing`.

Since your `T` is now `Nothing` in the context of your entire `Generic` class, your test function signature is now `test(value: Nothing)`. which is why you get your error when you try to pass in an Int into that `test` function.

As to your second point "Why can I pass in (Int) -> Unit"?

```
val generic = createGeneric { arg: Int -> println(arg) }
```

If you were to get rid of the `null` parameter, you can see that the next error that you get will be because you're passing in `(Int) -> Unit` and it can't correctly infer that parameter type to be true.