# Generics in Kotlin: How to instantiate generic class which implements an Interface

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, generics

My problem is I cannot instantiate a generic class when it implements an Interface.

The instantiation code is below;

```
class MainClass {
    fun mainMethod() {
        val access = EADBAccess<AppUserModel>(AppUserModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

in this main class I gen an error.
The error is

[image]

The other Respective classes are below.

**EADBModelI Interface**

```
interface EADBModelI {
    var id: String
}
```

**AppUserModel Class**

```
class AppUserModel : EADBModelI {
    override var id: String
        get() = id
        set(value) { id = value }
    
    var name: String
        get() = name
        set(value) { name = value}
    
}
```

**EADBAccess Class**

```
Class EADBAccess<in T : EADBModelI>(private val typeParameterClass: Class<T>) {
    fun getSingleDocument(source: Source = Source.DEFAULT, docRef: DocumentReference, handler: ResultHandlerI<T>) {

        docRef.get(source).addOnCompleteListener { taskResult ->
            if (taskResult.isSuccessful) {
                val snapshot = taskResult.result
                if (snapshot!!.exists()) {
                    val model : T = snapshot.toObject(typeParameterClass)
                    model!!.id = snapshot.reference.id
                    handler.onSuccess(model)
                }
            } else {
                handler.onFailure(taskResult.exception)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ResultHandlerI Interface**

```
interface ResultHandlerI<T> {
    fun onSuccess(data: T)
    fun onFailure(e: Exception)
}
```

Comment: I believe this code should work properly. Recheck everything, it seems like a some mistake. Maybe there are two distinct `EADBModelI` or `AppUserModel` definitions or something like this.

Comment: @broot I changed EADBModelI from interface to abstract class and it worked ;)

Comment: Something else: You might have simplified your code for this example, but the getters and setters in `AppUserModel` should use [the `field` identifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields), not `id` or `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code and made it executable (see 'Runnable code' at the bottom of this answer). When I ran it, I got an error:

```
Type parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'invariant' 
position in type ResultHandlerI<T>
```

#### Error location

Where does this happen? Well first, type parameter `T` is defined in the class `EADBAccess`. `T` is marked as `in`.

```kotlin
class EADBAccess<in T : EADBModelI>
```

The error occurs when `T` is also used as in parameter `handler` of `fun getSingleDocument`:

```
  fun getSingleDocument(source: String, docRef: String, handler: ResultHandlerI<T>) {
    // ...
  }
```

#### tl;dr

The quick fix is to remove `in`.

```kotlin
class EADBAccess<T : EADBModelI>
```

And now when I run the code it compiles, runs, and prints:

```
success: AppUserModel(id='docRef', name='source')
```

#### Explanation

The Kotlin documentation [Generics: in, out, where](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) goes into details.

> [...] Kotlin provides a [...] variance annotation: `in`. It makes a type parameter *contravariant*, meaning it can only be consumed and never produced.
>
> `Array<in String>` corresponds to Java's `Array<? super String>`.

So if `<in T : EADBModelI>` is used, then `T` will be some unknown implementation of the `EADBModelI` interface. But that's not clear enough - `ResultHandlerI` needs to know an **invariant** `T`, not a variable range.

While on one hand `T` is an input (and so `in T` makes sense), in effect, `T` is *also* an output, as it is being used to define the type of `ResultHandlerI`.

Defining `<T : EADBModelI>` makes `T` invariant - at runtime it will be a single, specific implementation of `EADBModelI` (which in your example is `AppUserModel`). This implementation of `T` can be used as both an input, and an output.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986410/4161471) for more explanation

> Function parameters which themselves allow input are logically equivalent to return values for a function, which are obviously in "out" position.

---

#### Runnable code

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val access = EADBAccess<AppUserModel>(AppUserModel::class.java)

  access.getSingleDocument("source", "docRef", PrintResult())
}

interface EADBModelI {
  var id: String
}

class AppUserModel : EADBModelI {
  override var id: String = ""
  var name: String = ""

  override fun toString() = "AppUserModel(id='$id', name='$name')"
}

class EADBAccess<in T : EADBModelI>(private val typeParameterClass: Class<T>) {

  fun getSingleDocument(source: String, docRef: String, handler: ResultHandlerI<T>) {
    // simplified example
    val model = AppUserModel()
    model.id = docRef
    model.name = source

    try {
      val result: T = typeParameterClass.cast(model)
      handler.onSuccess(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      handler.onFailure(e)
    }
  }
}

interface ResultHandlerI<T> {
  fun onSuccess(data: T)
  fun onFailure(e: Exception)
}

/** Dummy result handler, prints result to console */
class PrintResult<T> : ResultHandlerI<T> {

  override fun onSuccess(data: T) {
    println("success: $data")
  }

  override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
    println("failure")
  }
}
```